# Managed Identity - does it save Certificate cost?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity

Currently, we are using Certificate based Service Principal for our KeyVault. And this certificate is given by our customer and I assume they buy this certificate from an external certificate authority.

But when we use Managed Identity, Azure itself assign the certificate automatically which is invisible to the users.

So does that mean, if we use Managed identity, the customer would actually save the certificate cost? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. If you are using a managed identity, you don't have to worry about getting the certificate. We manage it. So to your point, yes. It's potentially a cost savings for the customer.